# RecyclerView By Using Same Adapter With Multiple AsynTask Loaders?

Tags: android

[image]

When I am adding multiple RecyclerViews in the same activity by using the same adapter and the same model class with two different AsyncTasks or AsyncLoaders and data. RecyclerView data is displaying, but only the data from one task is displaying in Both RecyclerViews.

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: You can use nested Recyclerview instead of multiple recyclerviews.